# SPO - Remove Document Library permissions in Powershell

Tags: powershell, spo

As part of an SPO site creation script, I want to remove ' Visitors' from the permissions of a document library that is created in the script.

I've got as far as breaking the inheritance, but how can I remove a specific group from the permissions?

Thanks in advance.

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSOM PowerShell, it would look something as mentioned in below code. Modify it as per your list and group names :

```
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName,$password)

$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $SPOCredentials

$web = $Ctx.Web

#load the groups
$groups = $web.SiteGroups
$Ctx.Load($groups)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# get the SharePoint group
$Group = $groups.GetByName("<Your Visitor Group Name>");
$Ctx.Load($Group);
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$listName = $Ctx.web.Lists.GetByTitle("Custom List")
$Ctx.Load($listName)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# break inheritance 
$listName.BreakRoleInheritance($true, $false)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# load the list role assignments
$Ctx.Load($listName.RoleAssignments)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# remove the visitor group from the list
$listName.RoleAssignments.Groups.Remove($Group)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks, will need a bit more help with this one please. Trying the below, but guess I'm missing something as I'm seeing an error: "The object is used in the context different from the one associated with the object."

I presume I need to start with this?

$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName,$password)

$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$Ctx.Credentials = $SPOCredentials

Comment: can you check with edited code ?

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error with Char 1 of this line, regardless of the group name: $Ctx.Load($Group);

Comment: can you check with edited code ? Hope this make things a bit clear

Comment: Thank you again... But now I have an error around the list name despite it matching the Document Library name exactly:

'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\temp\Scripts\Permissions4.ps1:29 char:1
+ $listName = $lists.getByTitle("Internal Files")'

Comment: make it `$listName = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Internal Files") ` , it has capital G

Answer (score 1):

This code can be used for this.It first breaks inheritance and then remove the specific group

```
$web=Get-SPWeb http://site url
$list = $web.Lists["list/library name"]
$list.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$true
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection] $spRoleAssignments=$list.RoleAssignments
for([int] $a=$spRoleAssignments.Count-1; $a -ge 0;$a--)
{
   if($spRoleAssignments[$a].Member.Name -eq "groupName")
   {
      $spRoleAssignments.Remove($a);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Get-SPWeb is for on-prem SharePoint isn't it? I need to do it in SharePoint Online. Cheers